# how to attach viewmodel to treeview in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

edit: rewording question.  My basic question was just where do should I place the viewmodel. Should I place it in a dictionary in App.xaml like so:

```
  <ResourceDictionary>
  <wpfExp:SignalDataViewModel x:Key="MainViewModel" />
  <wpfExp:DoubleToStringConverter x:Key="DoubleToStringConverter"/>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

My current idea is to have a viewmodel property contained in my Custom User Control. Then 
    public partial class SignalBox : UserControl
      {
     public SignalDataViewModel _SignalData
        {
          get;
          private set;
        }

What I was thinking is that I have two options. I can just bind the field here to the signaldataviewmodel inside the app resources, or I can just create it locally here inside the custom user control. I was just wondering whether it is better to have the signaldataviewmodel be an app resource or not. Technically the signaldataview that ties the model to the view  could be tied to other controls so I was thinking the proper place to locate it would be in app resources, so I was wondering if viewmodels are typically placed globally in app resources or whether something else is done with them.

edit: bottom part answered. 
Is there syntax available to bind extended paths or to children?

I have

```
ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path = _SignalData}
```

but I want to bind to _signals a child property of _SignalData.

Is there a syntax to get the child? like `Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path = _SignalData._Signals?` or something like the Binding RelativeSource but with descendants instead of ancestors?

Comment: well did you just say try `{Binding ElementName=signal_box, Path=_SignalData._Signals}` ?? cos if you did, you'd prolly have found out it works fine as long as `_Signals` is also a property. As for your main question. I'm just confused with your terms "viewmodel treeview", "custom control"(is this a `UserControl` ??). Please edit your question add some code-tags and show you put more effort into this question than me with this response.

Comment: There's a Josh Smith example using a HierarchicalDataTemplate which is fairly easy to follow: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode